# when calling a function to print, how do i get it to get user input from my void function?

Tags: python, function

I have a code that will turn a word into pig latin, I'm getting user input from a function. What do i need to put into the

```
print(convert_word(n))
```

to make it print with user input?

```
def void(n):
n = input("Enter the word you want converted to Pig Latin: ")
return n


VOWELS = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')

# Function definition

def convert_word(word):


# Assign the first letter of word to variable first_letter
first_letter = word[0]

# Check if the word starts with a vowel
if first_letter in VOWELS:

    # If it is a vowel, then keep the word as it is and add "hay" to the end
    return word + "hay"

# If the word does not start with a vowel
else:
        # Returns the word except word[0] and add "ay" at the end of the string
    return word[1:] + word[0] + "ay"


# Prompt the user to enter the input string


# Call the function to convert the word to pigLatin
print(convert_word(n))
```

Comment: Maybe you should just get rid of the void function altogether.

Comment: Why call it `void`?  The phrase “void function” has a (very different) meaning…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `void()` only calls `input()`, you could do away with that function entirely and just call `convert_word()` like this:

```
print(convert_word(input('some prompt >')))
```

If you really do need the `void()` function for some reason:

```
print(convert_word(void()))
```

If you like, you can change the declaration of `void()` to remove the input argument, as it is never used.

Comment: I do have to have to void function, it is a requirement. When I didn't put an input argument in the void function, I received this error:                                                   
  File "/Users/jess/PycharmProjects/assignmet3/assignemnt 3.py", line 32, in <module>
    print(convert_word(void()))
TypeError: void() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: I meant that you can edit the definition of `void()` to remove the input argument, as in: `def void():`.  If you really must use it exactly as written in the question, you can pass any argument you like, since it doesn't actually use the argument for anything.  Try `void(1)`.

Comment: I added the 1 into the `void()` like you suggested. and I received the following error:  ` File "/Users/jess/PycharmProjects/assignmet3/assignemnt 3.py", line 32, in <module>
    print(convert_word(void(1)))
  File "/Users/jess/PycharmProjects/assignmet3/assignemnt 3.py", line 2, in void
    n = input("Enter the word you want converted to Pig Latin: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sing' is not defined`

Comment: If you're using Python version 2, use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.